# Fontspec, tocloft and bfseries weird result

Tags: fontspec, tocloft

I am using `tocloft` and `fontspec` to reformat a table of contents.

I have this code:

```
\newfontface\Verdana{Verdana1}[
   Path=fonts/,
   Extension=.ttf,
   BoldFont=Verdana1b,
   BoldFeatures={SmallCapsFont={Verdana1b}}
]
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{12}\Verdana\selectfont\sc\bfseries\expandafter}
```

This is the result. Note the size of the chapter number, vs the size of the page number.

[image: Result]

If in the other hand, I switch`\bfseries` to `\bf` I get only a bold text with correct chapter number size; and if I use only `\sc` I also get a correct chapter number size, but not bold.

I have a solu^whack working:

```
% THESE TWO LINES HAVE A TWISTED HACK
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\fontsize{17}{12}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont.}
```

But then, it looks acceptable.

If you have any idea why this happen, and how to fix it, I am welcome.

Comment: `\normalfont\fontsize{10}{12}\Verdana\selectfont\sc` is the same as `\normalsize\sc` as the old latex2.09 compatibility commands such as `\sc` always select a fixed font not adapting to the current  font family. presumably you want `\scshape` (but not all families have bold small caps)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right. Just now I noticed that is Times, not Verdana. Using \scshape does nothing, although I added a small caps variant using fontforge.

Answer (score 1):

As David Carlisle pointed out, `\sc` was ignoring the font family. Using `\scshape` needs a font with that feature, a thing I did using FontForge.

My main issue was the way to configure correctly the fontface. This is the result that is working for me:

```
\newfontface\Verdana{Verdana1}[
   Path=fonts/,
   Extension=.ttf,
   BoldFont=Verdana1b,
   BoldFeatures = {Letters=SmallCaps},
]
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{12}\Verdana\selectfont\bfseries\scshape\expandafter}
```

So, `Verdana1b.ttf` has the bold font with small caps, but it seems that if I do not specify in its features the existence of SmallCaps, it will not be loaded.